# Sequence of execution of varoius files in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is a very basic questions although. I gone through the MVC life cycle but didn't find this basics.

We have `_Viewstart`, `_Layout`, views and partial views. Consider standard scenario where view is using `_Layout` file. There are partial views on both `_Layout` file and view. In what sequence all these files executes and when actual html is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests `_Viewstart` is the first one among the other view files to be processed. `_Viewstart` decides which layout file to be processed. You can have conditional code in the `_Viewstart` to choose the correct layout file depending on the controller like below

```
@{
   var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();

   string layout = "";
   if (controller == "Reports")
   {
       layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ReportsLayout.cshtml";
   }
   else
   {
       layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout1.cshtml";
   }

  Layout = layout;
}
```

So per my knowledge the order is as follows

```
1. _Viewstart
2. _Layout
3. Partial within layout
4. The actual view along with the partial within the view depending on the order as it appears
```

Comment: Thanks for response but didn't get how it render html at what point.

Comment: View in MVC is nothing but wherein you use the HTML helpers classes, scripts and other HTML tags etc to create your HTML file. When the view is rendered in browser look at the 'viewsource' you will see all HTML tags in there.